# Read out Ajax response from XMLHTTP using simple VBScript

Tags: vbscript, web, download, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to download a set of websites using a script:

```
dim xmlhttp : set xmlhttp = createobject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://www.website.com/tags/search-term?page=1, false

xmlhttp.send

text= xmlhttp.ResponseText
```

Firebug tells me the response is in DOM "_result". But how can I read this out? I know this is a very stupid question, but I just need to run a lot of automated searches for a research project and am struggling with implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the response from your object like so

```
response=xmlhttp.responseText
```